Why use "revived" instead of "revive" in "if your diet has lapsed it's time you revived it"?
The following sentence was found in Oxford Online Dictionary:

if your diet has lapsed it's time you revived it.

I can't see for myself why "revived" is being used here. I think it should be "revive" instead or it's some kind of clever use of English grammar here?

This is just a normal pattern of English grammar. We can say

It is time for you to [do something]

but without the for, we always use the past tense.

It is time [that] you [did something].

See this explanation

your answer is adequate for my question. I wanted to also know why it's the past tense being used here. In other words, what is the problem with "It's time you do [something]"? It would be great if you could further input some thought!

I don't know - you just have to accept that 'that's how we say it in English'.

@TranKhanh It's time you did your homework.  It's time you did some shopping. It's time you went home.  There is an implication here when using the past tense that the time has already passed by which you should have already done something, so you had better do it now without delay.

@BillyKerr, thanks, your explanation indeed makes a lot of sense to me!!!

@TranKhanh There are a number of expressions in English that use the past tense to express a hypothetical situation, even if that situation is in the present or the future. Some explanations here and here.
